# SQL server 2008 can't open after installing windows update

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have recently installed windows update on my windows server 2003 machine. After updates when i open sql server 2008, i'm getting a wired error: 'Failed to open connection dialog - object reference not set to an instance of object (Microsoft.sqlserver.sqltools.VSIntegration)'.

I have tried these things to resolve this issue but couldn't get it fixed:
1. Run SQL agent service under 'Local System' account.
2. un-installed sql server updates.
3. Tried to repair sql server 2008, but getting error during repair.

Does anyone came accross with this issue and remember solution for it?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the error is probably related to Visual Studio Integration. Anything that you might have done related to that is probably to blame.

Comment: Belongs on Server Fault

Comment: yea, i also think it's server issue. cause its a DB server and does't even have visual studio on it. I have also tried couple of options in 'Surface area configuration' with tcpip setting, but nthing worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to start SQL SErver services successfully?
From Windows Event Veiwer logs check for APplication & System logs to see if there any other related errors.

The error you referred seems to be a tools problem, so you might try reinstalling Client components from SQL 2008 media. FyI there is no Surface Area Configuration tool in 2008 version, all such tasks can be managed using SQL Server Configuration manager.

Comment: Thanks Satya. yes, sql server service was working fine. couldn't find any solution with so end up completely uninstalling SQL server and reinstall it. yea, it was configuration manager (sorry about that).